# How to add margin without adding additional space to parent div

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I create a sidebar drawer using react material ui and try to create the clicked item on the sidebar drawer style to be like in this example http://react-material-dashboard.devias.io/dashboard.

I use the code from here https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/demos/drawers/ResponsiveDrawer.js to create the drawer.

And add style like this for the active item.

```
const styles = () => ({
  clickedItem: {
    borderLeft: "4px solid #0767DB",
    borderRadius: "4px",
    backgroundColor: "#F6F9FD",
    marginLeft: "10px"
  }
});
```

However, because of I add the `marginLeft`, the sidebar is now scrollable in x axis because it adds additional space on the right side. I want it to add margin of left without affecting the right side. I try to use `overflow: "hidden"`. But, the y scroll bar is also hide and can't be scroll.

How to fix it so the item size (width) is still the same even though I add marginLeft?

Comment: Try to add padding instead of margin.

If you still need margin then try, overflowX: 'hidden', OverflowY: 'auto' in that way, you will have y scrollbar

Comment: @sarabs3 when I add padding it is not like what I want. When adding overflowX: "hidden" and overflowY: "auto", it's true that it remove the scrollbar for the x axis and still have scroll bar for y axis. However, the x axis is still scrolable even though without scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I had a play with the browser-inspect on the dashboard linked.

Try adding: `width:auto;` to the styles you're passing the active element. This will stop the margin being added to the fixed width indiscriminately and causing the overflow.

Just as a bonus, it might help to add `word-break: break-all;` to avoid any singular long words also causing an overflow in the drawer.

Hope this helps!